# GKE preemptible VMs using deployment manager

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-deployment-manager

I'm planning to completely adopt the GCP service creation unto Deployment Manager. But based on the documentation, I can not see any options on converting the nodes to be created into the cluster into preemptibles.

I am hoping that there is a way but just not written on the document as by experience there should be some options that are not written in the document.

Below is the jinja template for it

```
resources:
- name: practice-gke-clusters
  type: container.v1.cluster
  properties:
    zone: asia-east2-a
    cluster:
      name: practice-gke-clusters
      network: $(ref.practice-gke-network.selfLink)
      subnetwork: $(ref.practice-gke-network-subnet-1.selfLink)
      initialNodeCount: 1
      loggingService: logging.googleapis.com
      monitoringService: monitoring.googleapis.com
      nodeConfig:
          oauthScopes:
          - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
          - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
          - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
          - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
```

Answer (score 1):

Preemptible VMs are in [Beta](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/preemptible-vms) stage at Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). As per documentation, it seems you need to add [preemptible value as "True"](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/NodeConfig#FIELDS.preemptible) into the deployment script such as [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/blob/master/examples/v2/gke/python/cluster.py#L39).

Comment: I was able to add them via nodePools